# workout with the php returned array to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

my this php code is working for the $.ajax call which is below this code

```
    $family = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['send_txt'], $link);
$query = "SELECT imgurl FROM images WHERE family='$family'";

//Query database
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

//Output result, send back to ajax as var 'response'

$imgurl=array();
//$i=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $imgurl[]=$row['imgurl'];

        }
}
echo $imgurl;
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "thegamer.php",
        data:{send_txt: txt},
        success: function(data){
        $('#main-content').html(data);
        }   
        });
    });
});
```

it outputs just Array written at the #main-content div how to work with that array which are basically image paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you create array from mysql result ? your code can be simpler like this:

```
<?php
$family = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['send_txt'], $link);
$query = "SELECT imgurl FROM images WHERE family='$family'";

//Query database
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

//Output result, send back to ajax as var 'response'

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['imgurl'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try you page from the browser directly. Using JSON can help here:

```
echo json_encode($imgurl);
```

and using [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of plain `ajax`:

```
$.getJSON('thegamer.php', {send_text:text}, function(data) { … });
```

Comment: this is not working read my question the php file is returning but array is displayed

Comment: `data` is a JavaScript Array now, you cannot do `.html(data)` anymore.

Comment: what to do then ur code is not working my problem is to display that image paths into img tag

Comment: You're returning the image URL only from PHP, not any HTML, right? So: read the ******* manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/